# How i can create extension class for dom element in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Please advise how to implement an extension class for DOM elements in typescript.
Lets say I want to add two methods `enable` and `disable` to the standard DOM element methods.

So far, i have to do this:

```js
export class FormElement {
  public element: HTMLElement

  constructor(selector: string) {
    this.element = document.querySelector(selector)
  }

  public disable = (): void => {
    this.element.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  }

  public enable = (): void => {
    this.element.removeAttribute('disabled')
  }
}
```

At some place I want to get a DOM element extended by the FormElement class

```js
class SomeComponent {
  ...
  private get nameInput(): FormElement {
    return new FormElement('input#company_msisdn')
  }  

  private disableNameInput = (): void => {
    this.nameInput.disable()
  }
}
```

Looks good, but if you need to use the DOM methods of an element, it does not look very good:

```js
  ...
  private initializeNameInput = (): void => {
    this.nameInput.element.addEventListener('change', this.onNameInputChange)
  }
```

Tell me if there is a way to implement the FormElement class so that the call to the newly added methods and
to the DOM methods of the element looked the same:

```js
  this.nameInput.enable()
  this.nameInput.addEventListener('change', this.onNameInputChange)
```

?

For example i'm try create class with genric:

```js
class FormElement<T = HTMLElement> {
  private this.element

  constructor(selector: string) {
    this.element = document.querySelector(selector) as T
  }

  ...
}

const nameInput = new FormElement<HTMLInputElement>('#name-input')
nameInput.disable()
nameInput.addEventListener('change', this.onNameInputChange)
```

But it is not right code, please advise how to implement class and generic.

Comment: As far as I understood, you want to get rid of intermediate `element` property? correct? I still don't understand what is wrong with `this.nameInput.element.addEventListener('change', this.onNameInputChange)`

Comment: `.element.`  isnt clear solution for me.

Comment: Is that class really needed, since you are only encapsulating a private field, which is, as I understand, the thing, that you want to get rid of - a plain function like the following could help: `const getElementFromDOM = (selector: string) => document.querySelector(selector);` where as you can use it: `const nameInput = getElementFromDOM(someSelector); nameInput.addEventListener(...)`? What I mean is, is a functional approach feasible for you?

Comment: If you are doing OOP wither way, why not just inherit from the `HTMLElement` constructor?

Answer (score 3):

I see your pain with the intermediate property 'element'. If your requirement isn't fixed on 'it must be a class'. I'd suggest to you, to some alternatives, e.g. inject functions into the prototype or complete functional style.

Below you find three few approaches on how this could be solved.

## Approach 1 - Inject methods into the prototype

Consider this approach as syntactic sugar and can be very controversial.

```
// Types for your new methods, this extends the original HTMLElement interface
interface HTMLElement {
  enable: () => void;
  disable: () => void;
}

// Add concrete implementation of the new HTMLElement functions
HTMLElement.prototype.disable = function () {
  this.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}

HTMLElement.prototype.enable = function () {
  this.removeAttribute('disabled')
}

const getElementFromDOM = (selector: string): HTMLElement | null => document.querySelector(selector);

// usage
const nameInput = getElementFromDOM("input#name");
nameInput?.disable();
nameInput?.enable();
```

Downside: Newly added functions could interfere with already existing methods, for example, adding 'some' to the `Array` prototype would cause interference. This can be hard to track down or confuse others. A good keyword to mention here is 'prototype pollution'.

## Approach 2 - Functional style

Alternatively, instead of expanding the HTMLElement prototype, you could provide extra methods which take a HTMLElement as parameter to disable/enable elements, this could look like this:

```js
const disable = (element: HTMLElement) => element.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
const enable = (element: HTMLElement) => element.removeAttribute('disabled');

// usage
const nameInput = getElementFromDOM("input#name");
disable(nameInput);
enable(nameInput);
```

Downside: There is nothing like `nameInput.disable()` and therefore it cannot be mixed with `HTMLElement` functions as stated in your question (e.g. `nameInput.setAttribute(...)`).

## Approach 3 - Create a new element derived from HTMLElement

And if the previous approaches aren't an option for you and you definitely want a class the best approach to get rid of `.element.` is, to define a completely new element.

```js
class FormElement implements HTMLElement {
 // Here you would have to implement all methods etc, which HTMLElement already has
}
```

Downside: I hope this is obvious to all, a huge amount of 're-implementing' already existing functionality.

Comment: I like second approach the most. Dont think that changing the prototype is good idea

Comment: My personal approach would be to go with the second one. It's the one that's less likely to cause much re-work or confusion and seems the cleanest. Thanks for pointing out, I've added a small 'downside' description to each of the approaches.

Comment: Option 2 is probably the easiest to unit test too, so I'd go with that.